How Create a custom authentication extension for attribute collection start and submit events with Python?
I don't use .net for my stack. I look to integrate custom authentication extension. Is there a solution to work with azure function running with python ?
In the current documentation in Microsoft website we just have an exemple using C# : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/custom-extension-attribute-collection?tabs=start-continue%2Csubmit-continue
Thank you!

As per the  Eventgrid documentation, Azure functions is not a supported handler for the AzureAD or MSI authentication methods. For Azure AD and MSI, only webhooks are supported. So I would suggest you to create a http trigger function and expose it as a webhook endpoint. This webhook can be integrated with Azure AD so that the events can be  authenticated


How Create a custom authentication extension for attribute collection start and submit events with Python

You can use below code to do the same in Python:
For OnAttributeCollectionStart:
import logging as rilg
import json
from azure.functions import HttpRequest as hr, HttpResponse as hres

def main(req: hr) -> hres:
    rilg.info("Hello Rithwik, OnAttributeCollectionStart Stared")

    rith_bd = req.get_json()
    rilg.info(f"Input Body: {json.dumps(rith_bd)}")

    ri_out = {
        "data": {
            "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.onAttributeCollectionStartResponseData",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.attributeCollectionStart.continueWithDefaultBehavior"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    return hres(json.dumps(ri_out),status_code=200,mimetype="application/json")

Output:

For OnAttributeCollectionSubmit just change the ri_out in code to:
   ri_out = {
        "data": {
            "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.onAttributeCollectionSubmitResponseData",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.attributeCollectionSubmit.continueWithDefaultBehavior"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

